# When trying to create a folder on microsoft azure website in visual studio asp.net i get error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2012

I've only got 4 users on my pc, all have full control over everything on the directory, and i get this error in local (debug) mode, and in azure.

What im doing is trying to create a folder for a user to upload their files:

```
if (!Directory.Exists("~/"+Session["user_id"]+"/"))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("~/" + Session["user_id"] + "/");
}
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/" + Session["user_id"] + "/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
}
```

**What fixed it**

```
string mapa = (Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + Session["user_id"].ToString() + "/")));
            if (!Directory.Exists(mapa))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mapa);
            }

 FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + Session["user_id"].ToString() + "/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

This works locally, im still working on azurewebsites though

Comment: This `~/` is not a valid system path

Comment: i saw a guy do it in a tutorial, and thought it was valid, here is the full path now C:\Users\žan\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Upload_aspx\Upload_aspx\Content

Answer (score 0):

"microsoft azure website" i assume you refer to Azure App Service (formerly known as Azure Websites).

what is the full path for your folder? In Azure App Service, your web app is running in side a sandbox, you only have write access to sub folder that under "D:\home" or temp folder "D:\local\Temp".

Update:

my guess is Directory.Exists doesn`t resolve your path, while Server.MapPath treat your path as relative path. I suggest you use absolute path and read it from app setting, so that when you deploy you can update your app setting to a proper path in Azure

Comment: C:\Users\žan\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Upload_aspx\Upload_aspx\Content  is the full path on my pc, I want it to create a folder in the content folder, and the name would be after the user id

Comment: yes, and im trying to give asp.net access to the map, in the security tab, by adding the new user group, but the only thing i can find close to it is some IIS, process, idk if that will help on azure websites, which is what i would ideally need.

Comment: Even after adding the iis thing and giving it full permission doesnt change anything locally

Comment: if you are running on an local IIS server, try to grant full access to "IIS_IURS" to target folder, or update AppPool identity do your sign-in username/password.

Comment: Im on my home pc, and when i tried granting IIS IURS the full access to the folder, nothing changed, and i just did it again and locally nothing new happened, i should note that im writing my path like this now: 
                Directory.CreateDirectory("~/Content/" + Session["user_id"] + "/");

Comment: i thought you updated to not using "~/", i don`t think it is a valid path. can you change it to a absolute path and try again?

also it is better to use Path.Combine(...) instead of manually concat the path with slash

Comment: I thought this wont work on azure websites, thats why im using the shortened thing, nevertheless i will try your solution, and see if that works, thank you, ill update this if it works

Comment: let first try to figure out the error from your local machine. there is other way to solve the absolute path issue. e.g read the prefix of the path from environment variable

Comment: i made a reply, showing all the major things, but the path in the variable is correct, and it is correct in general, but the map still doesnt exist, even though the part about create directory gives no errors. Also im using the virtual path because the absolute wont work on azure

Answer (score -1):

This code

```
 if (!Directory.Exists("/Content/" + Session["user_id"] + "/"))
 {
       Directory.CreateDirectory("/Content/" + Session["user_id"] + "/");
 }
 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
 {
       FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Content/" + Session["user_id"] + "/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
 }
```

Currently gives this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG2Sf.png

Additional info:
the user id variable is 101 so the path is completely correct.
the path does not exist, because for some reason, the `Directory.CreateDirectory` doesn't create them (the folder), even though i added IIS IURS full access to the folder (I know because I'm running debug mode and i checked locally).

Comment: can you open windows explorer to see if those folder got created?

Comment: Yeah, as i said, it does not create the path/map, i dont know why, but the path is correct, however if i manually create a path myself then it can upload in it (obviously this does not work for me since im trying to create a site where everyone can upload their files, its a kind of project, doesnt need to be good efficient or nice, just working, and i need to have the maps properly sorted (each registered user his own in content).http://imgur.com/VCKruv2

Comment: my guess is Directory.Exists doesn`t resolve your path, while Server.MapPath treat your path as relative path.  I suggest you use absolute path and read it from app setting, so that when you deploy you can update your app setting to a proper path in Azure